# ssis Connection manager password ("DontSaveSensitive")

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package used the protection level as "DontSaveSensitive"
So initially I have saved the oledb connection manager password as in  a XML config file. And this worked fine for me.

Now for business requirement I have stored the configuration in SQL Server.
Including password.

Initially it worked fine.But suddenly connection manager is not taking password from sqlDB.

If I set an environment variable for the "password" it's working.

My question is:

1. what is the solution for this. (I can only save the configurations in SQL)
2. initially how it worked. I mean initially from SQL Server the password was taking.

Please give some clue. I am doing a lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to retrieve the password from the database if you need the password to connect the database?

There is a small article [here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/04/26/SSIS_3A00_-Storing-passwords.aspx) about storing passwords which may help you.